# undefinded variable projets

Tags: laravel, vue.js, controller

I’m having a problem.

I have this component called ProjetDetail. Inside of it, I have this block of code:

I want to get the projects from DB w but nothing Happen:

```
export default {
    data(){
        return{
        id: this.$route.params.id,
      projets:[],
        projet:{
             id:'',
       name:'',
       durre:'',
       description:'',
       budget:'',
       owner:'',
        }
        }
    },
    methods:{
        afficherProjet(){
       axios.get('api/id').then(({data}) => (this.projets = data.data));
        }
    },
    created(){
      this.afficherProjet()
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
    }
}
```

and this is my controller:

```
public function projet(){
    return Projet::latest()->paginate(15);
}
```

Comment: console.log(data) and And see what it shows

Comment: Ramin eghbalian nothing happen

Comment: Same result if you call `this.afficherProjet()` in mounted event?

Comment: Tpojka same result when console.log(data) he show me data  "ReferenceError: data is not defined"

Comment: I mean have you tried to full axios code put into mounted section?

Comment: Tpojka  same thing the projects still undefined for the vue

Comment: And if it is not shorted in code like `.then(function (response) { console.log(response);})`?

Comment: nothing too @Tpojka

Comment: Is that line executed at all? Under that console log put one more `console.log("executed")`.

Comment: it show the response and the executed now

Comment: Meaning now is working? have you change anything else and it suddenly worked?

Comment: no the first i haven't check it well but i don't understand why axios.get('api/id').then(({data}) => (this.projets = data.data)); didn't work

Comment: And if you put part of it in curly braces: `axios.get('api/id').then((data) => { this.projets = data.data });` and remove that object deconstructing (just for test purpose)?

Comment: no nothing work sorry

Comment: it show me in vue tools projets:undefined with  axios.get('api/id').then(({data}) => (this.projets = data.data));

Comment: Try to copy code I left you up in comment since I didn't use object deconstructing.

Comment: i use it but nothing happen

Comment: It's hard for me to debug this way, sorry. I used all my ideas. Check [this article](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and try to isolate exact part of code which makes erroneous behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function projet(){
    $projets = Projet::latest()->paginate(15);
    return response()->json(['data' => $projets]);
}
```

You are not sending the JSON encoded response from your function.